# Relative Path vs Absolute

Tags: excel, relative-path, absolute

I have two excel files. The first one (CF.xlsx) is linked to the source (PM.xlsx) with an index match formula. The linked file is used by multiple users and often from different computers so I am trying to create a relative path instead of an absolute path in the linked file (CF.xlsx). I have tried to move three steps "up" in the file path by using \ .. \ .. \ .. \ but it's not working. I am User1 in below path.

The Source is located at C:\Users\User1\Company Dropbox\Company International\Positions
and then the file name is PM.xlsx

The linked file with the reference to the source is located

```
C:\Users\User1\Company Dropbox\Company International\Admin\Cash Flow\AP and AR and reports and then file name is CF.xlsx
```

My formula in the linked file (CF.xlsx) is currently as follows:

```
=CELL("format",INDEX('C:\Users\User1\Company Dropbox\Company International\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$A$1:$CX$650,MATCH(F2,'C:\Company Dropbox\Company International\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$H$1:$H$650,0),MATCH(D2,'C:\Company Dropbox\Company International\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$A$1:$CX$1,0)))
```

To create the relative path, I changed the formula to the below:

```
=CELL("format",INDEX('C:\Company Dropbox\Company International\..\..\..\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$A$1:$CX$650,MATCH(F2,'C:\Company Dropbox\Company International\..\..\..\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$H$1:$H$650,0),MATCH(D2,'C:\Company Dropbox\Company International\..\..\..\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$A$1:$CX$1,0)))
```

It's still not working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Most of us are not strong with VBA so a solution with a formula path would be great!

Comment: A relative path cannot start with `C:\ `, that will always be an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you - but even when I remove C:\ and start with "'..\" it doesn't work. I just entered  =CELL("format",INDEX('..\Positions\[PM.xlsx]MgO-161'!$A$1:$CX$1,0)) and get a result on my PC which is great, but when I open the file on another PC, it goes back to #N/A.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete directory structure you have on your PC where the various files like `PM.xlsx` and `CF.xlsx` are located. Then add the directory structure from the other PC (or PCs), where these files are located in these directory structures.

Comment: Hi Progman, Is this what you mean? The source is located here: C:\Users\User1\Company Dropbox\Company International\Positions and then the file name is PM.xlsx and the linked file is located here: C:\Users\User1\Company Dropbox\Company International\Admin\Cash Flow\AP and AR and reports. The only  different by user is me (User 1) and the other PC is User2 but the path is the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these information to your post, not as a comment.

Comment: Hi Progman, I actually had in there from the beginning. In regards to the question, do you know how I can change it to a relative path? Thank you

Comment: A relative path is a path which is based of a given start point, usually the current file or current directory. Based from that location you select the directories and files you want to load. Use `../` if you need to go to the previous directory. Depending on your directory structure the relative path might be as simple as `'..\Admin\Cash Float\AP'`. The relative path does **not** start with a drive letter or with a `\`, these would be absolute paths.